# Calculating Number IDs

Tags: javascript, class, dom

I wasn't quite sure how to word this in the title, so thank you for clicking to on this.

So now to my problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .block {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
<table border='1px'>
    <tr>
        <td id='11'></td>
        <td id='12'></td>
        <td id='13'></td>
        <td id='14'></td>
        <td id='15'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='21'></td>
        <td id='22'></td>
        <td id='23'></td>
        <td id='24'></td>
        <td id='25'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='31'></td>
        <td id='32'></td>
        <td id='33' class="block"></td>
        <td id='34'></td>
        <td id='35'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='41'></td>
        <td id='42'></td>
        <td id='43'></td>
        <td id='44'></td>
        <td id='45'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='51'></td>
        <td id='52'></td>
        <td id='53'></td>
        <td id='54'></td>
        <td id='55'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="blockUp()">Up</button>
<button onclick="blockDown()">Down</button>
<button onclick="blockLeft()">Left</button>
<button onclick="blockRight()">Right</button>
<script>
var blockUp = function() {
    var oldBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0].id;
    var newBlock = Math.floor(oldBlock + 1);
    document.getElementById(newBlock).classList.add("block");
    document.getElementById(oldBlock).classList.remove("block");
}

    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is not complete, as I want to fix this problem first.

I want to use Math.floor to get a certain ID (thus, IDs as numbers), and manipulate them. More specifically, I want to find the ID of the cell that currently has the .block class, find the ID of the cell above that using Math.floor(oldBlock + 1), remove the class from the original cell, and add the class to the new cell. I used variables so that the function would always be able to run, rather than making a million if/else if/else statements.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with my current code. How would I be able to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `oldBlock` is a string you concatenate 1 onto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that "oldBlock" contains a number before trying to do math with it (like adding 1):

```
var oldBlock = +document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0].id;
```

That's one way of doing it. You could also use `parseInt()`:

```
var oldBlock = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0].id, 10);
```

The value of the "id" property will be a string, so if you involve that in an addition operation JavaScript will treat it as string concatenation. By forcing it to be a number first, you'll get the effect you want.

Comment: With the exception that his `blockUp` appears to move the selected cell to right :/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Pointy! I added the + sign and it works fine now. Also, I figured that out in the test j08691...